# How to fix "An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the ModifySecurityGroupRules operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to add a rule to an EC2 security group using the AWS CLI.

Here is the command I run, and the output (with some parts redacted):

```
$ aws --profile **** ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id sg-***************** --security-group-rules '[{
    "SecurityGroupRuleId": "SSH",
    "SecurityGroupRule": {
        "Description": "Allow SSH",
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "ToPort": 22,
        "CidrIpv4": "***.***.***.***/32"
    }
}]'

An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the ModifySecurityGroupRules operation: Request has expired.
```

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html) has the following to say about what this error means:

> The request reached the service more than 15 minutes after the date stamp on the request or more than 15 minutes after the request expiration date (such as for presigned URLs), or the date stamp on the request is more than 15 minutes in the future. If you're using temporary security credentials, this error can also occur if the credentials have expired. For more information, see Temporary Security Credentials in the IAM User Guide.

The date stamp on the request should not be 15 minutes before or after the expiration date, from what I can tell. The output of `date` looks fine.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was my temporary credentials that I had created with [`aws-adfs`](https://pypi.org/project/aws-adfs/) had expired.

Once I reran my `aws-adfs login` command, I was able to run the `aws ec2` command (though I got a different error for the `SecurityGroupRuleId` being malformed, but that is a different problem).